# image uploading and fetching problem

Tags: php, sql

my image name is like this:-- demo 123.jpg

can i save that image name demo 123 in database column. And in also in folder as demo 123.jpg

when i am fetching with demo 123.jpg it can not find image name because..

peoblem is space in name of image...

i dont want to replace space in image name with any character like _

can i do it without it.?

Comment: Write the exact SQL query you've tried using.

Comment: The problem is not the SQL query I think problem is the space,am I right.Are you applying source to image by java script,y I am asking because if you are then java script may be the reason..Please specify where's the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
`demo 123.jpg`
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make sure that when the image is saved, all the spaces are converted to - or _ using a regular expression like this

> preg_replace('/\s/i', '-', 'demo 123.text');

This will make sure all spaces are converted to hyphens.  Now save this name into your database and also use that name to rename the file when its uploaded.